# wordpress responsive menu not dropping down

Tags: menus

I've been trying to get my WordPress responsive menu to toggle when a button is clicked, however, once the button is clicked, the menu slides down and then back up right awaY. I can't figure out where I've gone wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Below is the code I am using:

**HTML**

```
<nav id="third-menu" class="mobile-menu" role="navigation">

    <button class="menu-toggle">Menu</button>

    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 
        'theme_location' => 'third-menu', 
        'menu_class' => 'third-menu', 
        'menu_id' => 'third-menu-nav' ) ); ?>

</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {


    .menu-toggle, .mobile-menu{
        display: block;
    }


    .first-menu-nav, .second-menu-nav{
        display: none;
    }


    .mobile-menu ul.third-menu-nav,
    .mobile-menu div.third-menu-nav > ul {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;
        border-top: 1px solid #ededed;
        display: inline-block !important;
        text-align: left;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .mobile-menu ul {
        margin: 0;
        text-indent: 0;
    }

    .mobile-menu li a,
    .mobile-menu li {
        display:block;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .mobile-menu li a {
        border-bottom: 0;
        color: #6a6a6a;
        line-height: 3.692307692;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    .mobile-menu li a:hover,
    .mobile-menu li a:focus {
        color: #000;
    }

    .mobile-menu ul.third-menu-nav,
    .mobile-menu div.nav-menu > ul {
        display: none;
    }

    .mobile-menu li ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
        height: 1px;
        width: 1px;
        overflow: hidden;
        clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
    }

    .mobile-menu li ul ul {
        top: 0;
        left: 100%;
    }

    .mobile-menu ul li:hover > ul,
    .mobile-menu ul li:focus > ul,
    .mobile-menu .focus > ul {
        border-left: 0;
        clip: inherit;
        overflow: inherit;
        height: inherit;
        width: inherit;
    }

    .mobile-menu li ul li a {
        background: #efefef;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;
        display: block;
        font-size: 11px;
        font-size: 0.785714286rem;
        line-height: 2.181818182;
        padding: 8px 10px;
        padding: 0.571428571rem 0.714285714rem;
        width: 180px;
        width: 12.85714286rem;
        white-space: normal;
    }

    .mobile-menu li ul li a:hover,
    .mobile-menu li ul li a:focus {
        background: #e3e3e3;
        color: #444;
    }

    .mobile-menu .current-menu-item > a,
    .mobile-menu .current-menu-ancestor > a,
    .mobile-menu .current_page_item > a,
    .mobile-menu .current_page_ancestor > a {
        color: #636363;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .menu-toggle .toggled-on{
        display: block;
    }


 }
```

**JS**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

  $('.third-menu-nav').hide();

  $('.menu-toggle').click(function () {
    $('.third-menu-nav').slideToggle("slow", function () {
        // Animation complete.
    });

  })

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the click event is being bound to your .menu-toggle button more than once.

One possible fix is to unbind the click event first, but this is not ideal:

```
$('.menu-toggle').unbind('click').click(function () {...
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829871/slidetoggle-executing-twice-in-one-call

A better solution would be to try and work out how the click event could be added twice?

Also, it seems like in your code:

```
$('.third-menu-nav').slideToggle("slow", function () { ...
```

Should be:

```
$('#third-menu-nav').slideToggle("slow", function () { ...
```